# Fetch the fields of different doc type in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I am querying in one doc type of the index. Create bucket of the results.

Now what I want to do is fetch fields from another doc type. I am not sure if it is possible or not.

There is common field in both doc type. So is there any vlookup in elastic

EDIT: I want to use join sort of concept in elastic. Like the doc type below.

```
PUT /my_index/user/1
{
  "name":     "John Smith",
  "email":    "john@smith.com",
  "dob":      "1970/10/24"
}

PUT /my_index/blogpost/2
{
  "title":    "Relationships",
  "body":     "It's complicated...",
  "user":     1
}
```

Now when I query for term in blogpost. I should be able to access the user details too. 
Not sure how to define schema for that & what to pass in fields array while querying.

Comment: Please show sample documents of both types and elaborate more on what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is the exact same example specified in elasticsearch official docs specifying the limitations and alternative approach. Is there anything specific you need to ask? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html